# Jar unable to read properties from implementing project

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, microservices, properties-file

I have 2 micro-services created using spring boot.

The first project is where I have created some DAOs to fetch data from a database.

The second project has a dependency on the first project, the need being that the first project should refer connection properties from the second project.

I am unable to achieve this as the first project containing the actual code for creation of data-source and the CRUD calls is always reading the properties from it's own application properties.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: You should extract the common functionality from both the project into a new library and use that library as dependency in above two spring boot projects.

Comment: There isn't any common functionality between the 2 boot projects. 1st project has some code for doing crud operation on a database. 2nd project needs to use this code to implement the actual business logic.

Comment: " first project should refer connection properties from the second project."  this statement tells both use some common thing which needs to be extract out from first project and put it new library/project.

Comment: So creating 2 microservices and use them to inter-communicate with each other?

Comment: as in send a request from the second micro-service to the first micro-service to make DAO calls